# I'm making sport live score application and I have a question

Tags: american-english, sentence

I'm making sport live score application and I have a question

My application has many page for show live score and it has some page no any match playing.

What sentences should i use ?

No any match on this day.
No match on the day.
This day has no any match.

Thank you

ps.sorry for my bad english

Comment: This question is off topic because it is asking for writing advice and answers are subjective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

no matches today

no matches today